# detect pictures whether qr-code or not

Tags: android, bitmap, qr-code, zxing

I'v been using zxing core recently, but I'v no idea how to detect a bitmap or other picture types whether a QR code or not. Any help can fix this? Using zxing is better while other libraries is OK.Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First You have to learn what is a QR code it is a  two-dimensional barcode.you convert normal text to QR code and read a QR code to convert to string.

in zxing you can make a qr code from this code

```
public static Bitmap encodeToQrCode(String text, int width, int height){
    QRCodeWriter writer = new QRCodeWriter();
    BitMatrix matrix = null;
    try {
        matrix = writer.encode(text, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 100, 100);
    } catch (WriterException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++){
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++){
            bmp.setPixel(x, y, matrix.get(x,y) ? Color.BLACK : Color.WHITE);
        }
    }
    return bmp;
}
```

the above code produce a bitmap image you can display it to an imageview.and remember this qr code readers decode QR codes to string.it dosn't work if the QR code not properly encoded

Comment: I know those functions, decode and encode. My question is how to detect pictures whether a qr-code or not. I'v thought of using decoding function, but it's inefficient. Anyway, thanks for your help. : )

Comment: scan it with qr code reader if  you want to detect it without a camera you have to find some java framework for image pattern recognition.

Comment: What is "qr code reader"?

Comment: I'v found a way to fix this. See http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/How-to-detect-QR-code2D-bar-code-in-an-image-using-Zxing-library-2182.php